# Como retornar os valores da tabela usando a função SUM()?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho as seguintes tabelas

```
CREATE TABLE tbCliente
( ClienteID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  ClienteNome VARCHAR(50),
  ClienteTelefone VARCHAR(15),
  ClienteDataCadastro DATE)

 CREATE TABLE tbPagamento
( PagamentoID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  ClienteID INT,
  PedidoID INT,
  PagamentoValor DECIMAL(8,2),
  PagamentoData DATE)

CREATE TABLE tbPedido
( PedidoID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  PedidoData DATE,
  ClienteID INT)

CREATE TABLE tbProduto
( ProdutoID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  ProdutoNome VARCHAR(50),
  ProdutoValor DECIMAL(5,2))

CREATE TABLE tbPedidoItem
( PedidoItemID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  PedidoID INT,
  ProdutoID INT)

ALTER TABLE tbPagamento  WITH CHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_tbPagamento_tbCliente
FOREIGN KEY(ClienteID) REFERENCES tbCliente (ClienteID)

ALTER TABLE tbPagamento  WITH CHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_tbPagamento_tbPedido
FOREIGN KEY(PedidoID) REFERENCES tbPedido (PedidoID)

ALTER TABLE tbPedido  WITH CHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_tbPedido_tbCliente
FOREIGN KEY(ClienteID) REFERENCES tbCliente (ClienteID)

ALTER TABLE tbPedidoItem  WITH CHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_tbPedidoItem_tbPedido
FOREIGN KEY(PedidoID) REFERENCES tbPedido (PedidoID)

ALTER TABLE tbPedidoItem  WITH CHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_tbPedidoItem_tbProduto
FOREIGN KEY(ProdutoID) REFERENCES tbProduto (ProdutoID)
```

e preciso retornar os pagamentos dos clientes que foram maiores que 50

```
select soma.ClienteID
from ( select tbCliente.ClienteID, sum(tbPagamento.PagamentoValor > 50) as preco
        from tbCliente
        group by ClienteID
        having sum(tbPagamento.PagamentoValor > 50,0) as soma
        inner join tbPagamento
        on tbPagamento.ClienteID = soma.ClienteID
```

é o que eu tenho até agora e não está funcionando

Comment: Você precisa retornar uma lista de pagamentos maiores que 50? Ou uma lista de clientes cuja soma dos pagamentos é > 50?

Comment: Lista de pagamentos maiores que 50, com o nome de cada cliente

Comment: Então pra que você acha que precisa de soma e agrupamento?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se entendi o que você quer, não precisa de agrupamento nem soma, seria algo assim:

```
SELECT 
    tbCliente.ClienteID, 
    tbCliente. ClienteNome, 
    tbPagamento.PagamentoValor
FROM tbCliente
INNER JOIN tbPagamento 
ON tbPagamento.ClienteID = tbCliente.ClienteID
WHERE tbPagamento.PagamentoValor > 50
ORDER BY tbPagamento.PagamentoData
```